# WooCommerce Settings Not Visible on Payment Page

Tags: woocommerce

I seem to be facing an issue regarding the visibility of certain payment settings in WooCommerce on my WordPress website. After adding certain settings in the “Payments” section, they are not visible at all **Despite trying several diagnostic steps, the problem persists, whereas it works correctly for another user on a different device.**

Here's what I've attempted:

- Clearing browser cookies,
- Clearing the cache on the site by emptying the cache using
  LiteSpeed - LSCache
- Trying a different browser in incognito mode.
- I tried accessing it on other devices.

Unfortunately, none of these steps have resolved the issue, suggesting that the problem may have a different underlying cause. Are there any additional troubleshooting steps I could take to address this issue effectively?